# Set systems with "small" intersections

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Are there infinite cardinals $\kappa < \lambda$ such that here is a collection ${\cal A}$ of subsets of $\lambda$ with the following properties:

1. $|{\cal A}| = 2^\lambda$, and
2. $A\neq B\in {\cal A}$ implies $|A\cap B|\leq \kappa$.

Comment: There is a vast literature on this, e.g., J. E. Baumgartner: Almost-disjoint sets the dense set problem and the partition calculus, Annals of Mathematical Logic, 9(1976), 401-439.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer! Unfortunately I dont have access to it. Does it answer my question?

Comment: You do have access: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484376900188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick observation: suppose $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$. Then we can mimic the construction of an almost disjoint set of sets of natural numbers of size continuum: to each map $p: \kappa^+\rightarrow 2$, we associate the set of *small approximations* $A_p=\{p\upharpoonright\alpha:\alpha<\kappa^+\}$. By $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ we have a bijection from partial maps from $\kappa^+$ to $2$ with bounded domain, and $\kappa^+$ itself; so we may replace each $A_p$ with a corresponding $B_p\subseteq \kappa^+$. The collection $\{B_p: p\in 2^{\kappa^+}\}$ is a collection of subsets of subsets of $\kappa^+$, with cardinality $2^{\kappa^+}$, with pairwise intersections of sizes $\le\kappa$.

So in order to have any hope for your principle to *fail*, we would need to work in a universe where GCH fails everywhere; and the global failure of GCH [has large cardinal strength](https://mathoverflow.net/a/80077/8133).

Comment: I thought a $\Delta$-system was a family of sets whose pairwise intersections were identical. Did the nomenclature change, or was I always wrong about that?

Comment: @bof The body of the question does not use the word "$\Delta$-system," and the way the second condition is phrased makes it sound very *not* $\Delta$-systemy; I'm taking the body over the title here. The OP of course can indicate whether I'm actually addressing their question.

Comment: Thanks @NoahSchweber! 1) I would like to wait for a while till I accept the answer to see whether somebody comes up constructing ${\cal A}$ with the disired properties within ${\sf ZFC}$; 2)Re: Terminology, I apologize if I used $\Delta$-system in a wrong way, but I'm reluctant to change the title.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Can you clarify what is the actual connection between this question and $\Delta$-systems?

Comment: Oh - I thought the set system I defined in the question is referred to as "$\Delta$-system". What is the correct term? - I'll change the title to "Set systems [...]"

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I don't know if there's a specific term for what you're asking about, but a $\Delta$-system is a collection of sets with the *same* intersection, not small intersection; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower_(mathematics)).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for your comment, and sorry for creating some confusion by my wrong use of $\Delta$-system